# Can K-FOLD Cross Validation and its variants be used for verifying the authenticity of labeled text data?

Tags: cross-validation

It is understandable that using K-Fold cross validation (or its variants such as Stratified K-Fold or repeated K-fold) is a popular method for dividing data (training and testing) in to number of folds to check the accuracy of a classifier.

Can it be used to check the authenticity of labeled text data? For instance, can we use it to make sure that labels corresponding to the text (or vice versa) are accurate?

Guidance with *reference* is highly appreciated please.

Comment: What would you compare the labels to when checking the accuracy? You can do it to compare two different labelings, and see if they match. But if you only have one labeling of the data, you would have nothing to compare it to.

Comment: @BlueEyedDaisy I have multilabeled text data and I want to ensure the authenticity of the labels by using K-Fold corss validation. If I attain consistent classification results then does it make sense the classes are correctly labeled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trivial counterexample: imagine that you want to classify tweets by gender of their author, but the labels you have are reversed (tweets by males are labeled as “female” and tweets by females as “male”). Your classifier could get perfect reproducibility in k-fold cross-validation, but this would not help with diagnosing the problem because technically the labels are correct, but you have their meaning wrong.

Comment: Much appreciated. Thank you for clarifying it.